# Notice: Undefined index error

Tags: php, html

```
<form action='login.php' method='POST'>
    Username: <input type='text' name='Username'><BR>
    Password: <input type='password' name='Password'><BR>
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" >  Rember Me
    <input type='submit' value='Log in'>
    <a href="reg.php"> Register </a>

<?php
session_start();
include 'db.php';

$Username = $_POST['Username'];
$Password = $_POST['Password'];

if ($Username&&$Password)
{ 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * From Users WHERE Username='$Username'");

$numrow = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($numrow!=0)

{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
      $Username = $row['Username'];
      $Password = $row['Password'];
    }

    // check to see if they match
    if ($Username==$Username&&$Password==$Password)
    {
      echo "You're in. <a href='index.php'>Click</a> here to enter the member page";
      $_SESSION['Username']=$Username;
    }

    else
      echo "Incorrect password";
}
else 
  die("That user doesn't exist");

}
else 
  die ("please enter a username and a password");

?>
```

The error im getting is :

Notice: 
Undefined index: Username in /home/stud/0/1314683/public_html/MathsrUs/login.php on line 48 Notice: Undefined index: Password in /home/stud/0/1314683/public_html/MathsrUs/login.php on line 49

Comment: Your code in one file or in two separate file. Also your file action is something but your button which is a link is taking you somewhere else?

Comment: both are in in same file called login.php with html and php.

Answer (score 0):

There is no data in $_POST

```
$Username = $_POST['Username'];

$Password = $_POST['Password'];
```

Check if page get accessed with via POST, you can check if with **$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']** variable.

Comment: when i put that code. i get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/stud/0/1314683/public_html/MathsrUs/login.php on line 49

Comment: Just check this - <form action='login.php' method='POST'>
    Username: <input type='text' name='Username'><BR>
    Password: <input type='password' name='Password'><BR>
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" >  Rember Me
    <input type='submit' value='Log in'>
    <a href="reg.php"> Register </a>
<?php
session_start();
include 'db.php';
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
$Username = $_POST['Username'];
$Password = $_POST['Password'];
print_r($_POST);die;
}. I removed all other code for just your understanding purpose that what you mistaken.OutputScreenshot:-- http://prntscr.com/722t7r